# Texto siempre misma posicion sobre img y con proporcion a la imagen en html y CSS

Tags: css, html5, imagen

Estoy haciendo pruebas con posicionamiento de texto sobre una imagen. Tengo esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto lo consigo con este codigo. En html:

```
<main>
    <div class="caja">
        <img src="smartphones.png" alt="" >
        <div class="texto">
            <h2>texto</h2>
            <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

En el CSS:

```
  .caja{
    position: relative;
}
img{
    width: 100%;
}
.texto{
    color: red;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 50px;
    font-size: 3rem;

}
```

Bien. Con esto si redimensiono la pantalla la imagen se redimensiona. Quedando algo asi (depende el tamaño pantalla el texto tendrá obviamente tendra diferente posicion):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La pregunta es: ¿Hay alguna manera que el texto siempre se mantenga en la misma posición y tenga un tamaño acorde al tamaño de la imagen? 
Tengo la solución de poner medias querys y posiciones y tamaño de texto acordes. ¿Pero se podría hacer de forma automática? ¿Alguna librería para poner texto sobre imágenes?

He probando a poner el font-size como vw y algo arregla... pero aun asi no es lo que quiero.

Un saludo y gracias.

Comment: ¿Y por qué no te sirve poner el tamaño de fuente con vw? Hace justo eso que pides: http://jsfiddle.net/blonfu/osgp6v2b/9/

Answer (score 2):

No utilices porcentajes ni pixels, usa vw para todas las medidas, incluido el tamaño de las fuentas.

Y acuerdate de poner un limite media query max-width que deje los anchos en pixels a partir de cierta medida del navegador si fuera necesario (si tuvieras todo esto en un div con el ancho limitado).

```css
   .caja{
position: relative;
}
img{
width: 100%;
}
.texto{
color: red;
position: absolute;
bottom: 1vw;
left: 0.5vw;
font-size: 5vw;

}
```

```html
<main>
<div class="caja">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/100" alt="" >
    <div class="texto">
        <h2>texto</h2>
        <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</p>
    </div>
</div>
</main>
```

Comment: Excelente!!! Eso es justo lo que buscaba mil gracias. No se me habia ocurrido poner el botom y left como vw. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a usar span y usar % en bottom y left, aquí te dejo un ejemplo

```css
.caja{
    position: relative;
}
img{
    width: 100%;
}
.title{
    color: red;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20%;
    left: 4%;
    font-size: 5em;
}
.contain{
    color: red;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10%;
    left: 4%;
    font-size: 2.5em;
}
```

```html
<main>
    <div class="caja">
        <img src="smartphones.png" alt="" >
        <div class="texto">
            <span class="title">texto</span>
            <span class="contain">Lorem, ipsum dolor.</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
```